# How to download/access/read a file from Azure file share via shared access signature (SAS)? (not blob)

Tags: azure, azure-files

there is an API that looks like:

```
https://{storage-account-name}.file.windows.net/{name(no suffix, may be a folder)}?sv={Date}&ss=f&srt=o&sp=rwl&se={Date}T{Time}Z&st={Date}T{Time}Z&spr=http&sig={token}
```

I want to access, read or download the file with this SAS URI somehow.

I tried to connect the SAS with Azure storage explorer, but it showed that

```
"The SAS cannot be used to connect to a storage account. An account SAS with at least service-level access ('srt=s') is required."
```

I tried to add "s" in the "srt" but apparently it is not working, Server failed to authenticate the request.

I also tried azcopy:

```
azcopy copy "https://<storage-account-name>.file.windows.net/<name(no suffix, may be a folder)>?sv=<Date>&ss=f&srt=o&sp=rwl&se=<Date>T<Time>Z&st=<Date>T<Time>Z&spr=http&sig=<token>" "C:\Users\<User>\Desktop" --recursive --preserve-smb-permissions=true --preserve-smb-info=true
```

but it returned an error showing:

```
"403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type."
```

I also want to try `Get-AzStorageFileContent` with Azure Powershell, but I don't know how to get the path with SAS URI.

Comment: Do you know the path of the file that you want to download?

Comment: I don't. The only thing I have is the SAS URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the SAS Token you have, you won't be able to download the files.

Here are the reasons for that:

- The SAS URL you have is for a file share. What that means is that you will need to list files first in that file share and only then you can download the file.
- The SAS Token you have does not have sufficient permissions to list the files in a file share. In order to list files in a file share, your `signed resource type (srt)` should have `container (c)` permission. Currently it only has `object (o)` permission which enables you to directly work with the files (that's why I asked that question in comment).

You simply cannot change the SAS URL and add `container` permission in `signed resource type`. This is because the `signature (sig)` portion of the SAS URL is calculated based on the permissions when SAS Token was created. This is why you are getting 403 error when you manually changed the SAS URL.

Solution to your problem is to request a new SAS URL with signed resource type as both `container` and `object` (it should look like `srt=co`. Then you will be able to list the files in the file share (because of `container`) and read/download the file (because of `object`).

Comment: Thank you, I will ask for a new SAS and try again.